# Issue in v1 Migrate from legacy FCM APIs to HTTP v1 getting error 400 Bead Request The registration token is not a valid FCM registration token

Tags: java, firebase, rest, firebase-cloud-messaging

currently i am integrating v1 api of push notification Migrate from legacy FCM APIs to HTTP v1 and i am facing issue of **The registration token is not a valid FCM registration token** and in my case i've generated the OAuth token from the **https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/** platform and i am having request type post having url-https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/cedar-freedom-396911/messages:send and i am sending the OAuth token in authorization tab .
Note.i am generating OAuth token from my dummy project of Firebase w.r.t client id and client secret.
still getting error

i have tried many times and my oauth token is generted successfully and my android token is also working with last api of push notoification but in this updated api i am getting error of The registration token is not a valid FCM registration token provide me steps to resolve this isssue.

[Postman image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIJUp.png)
[Postman image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHbu6.png)